# Rails 3. How to setup Prawn with ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, activeadmin, prawn

Has anybody been able to setup Prawn with ActiveAdmin?

ActiveAdmin changes the controllers so where would you setup the show action for example?

Answer (score 2):

See this controller. 
https://github.com/ianmurrays/active_invoices/blob/master/app/admin/invoices.rb#L116
I use action_item, then I send it to controller with prawn-rails.
Hope you can get a better idea